# How to review new code before merging in a local-based git environment

Tags: git

Me and my friend will work in a project and will share the same disk but different personal areas. My friend is the owner of the project and he has a git local repository.
So I clone the repository to my personal area. No issues so far.

I'll make changes in the content and I'll push the changes. But my friend wants to validate the push before changing the contents in the repository. How can we do that?

Basically here is what we have done:

At my side

- Created a test file
- `git add test.txt`
- `git commit -m "Add new file"`
- `git push origin master`

At my friend side

- He needed to change `.git` permissions from `755` to `775` so I can commit
- He needed to change something more (can't precisely remember at the time) but when he made the change he stopped to be able to do `git status` or `git pull`.

What we wanted is when I perform `git push`, the changes are only at the repo after he validates (like pushing OK button). I know there is something like this in GitHub if I'm not mistaken but I'd like to know if it is possible in git too.

Comment: Push your changes on a branch, and send them a pull request by mail or IM. What have you tried?

Comment: Basically at my side I did this:

1º Created a test file
2º git add test.txt
3º git commit -m "Add new file"
4º git push origin master

Comment: Post edited with more information

Comment: If you want a pull request interface and more permissions than the file system offers, you need a hosted Git, either on some hub or bucket or locally.

Comment: ohh ok I thought it was possible with git shell only. Ok thanks for the support!

Comment: @CodeCaster that's not true. Git is a distributed system. You may create a bare repository (`git init --bare`), set it as remote for both you and your colleague, push to and pull from it. You'll have "the" repository and two working copies. There is no need _at all_ to get third party software.

Comment: @DaemonPainter the question here is about reviewing pull requests instead of letting others push into (certain branches of) a repository directly. You need an interface for that, or do it per mail (`git request-pull`).

Comment: @miguelfcp I don't see why your friend is changing permissions. Can you elaborate on that? You should implement some branch workflow, so that you both are working on different branches and don't interfere. One of you two should be _in charge_ of merging content from the both of you into a blessed (or master) branch.

Comment: @miguelfcp you may even do it with only 1 Working Copy: since you cannot work at the same time, just branch out and change branch every time you develop. Probably you are better off with at least two working copies or two working copies and a bare copy. GitHub is nothing more than a decorated bare repository with added stuff for the industry sake. Same goes for bitbucket and the rest of them.

Comment: @CodeCaster push to a branch, review it on the branch, after the review integrate it on the integration branch. No need to do further stuff via email. The stable code is preserved, the reviewed branch can be removed from the "blessed" repository.

Comment: @Daemon there has to be had communication back and forth, to announche a branch has been pushed to review, and to send feedback on whether the branch was accepted or why not. This can be done verbally (no recorded history) or per mail (introducing out-of-band communication). A hosted Git environment makes all this stuff available seamlessly in one place. Yes, you could do it all by hand and on disk to get to know what happens in the background, but once you do understand that, you'll see that an organised web interface can make communication go more smoothly.

Comment: @CodeCaster or, once a commit is ready for integration, that commit is marked in the message somehow, or tagged, and there is only a single document explaining the procedure. Document that you _should_ have as well even with an hosted solution. So, the commit message records the information for integration, or the tag message does, and no email is needed (again). The merge message contains the review results. A tag can be added again to refuse integration. All done within git...

Comment: @Daemon I'm familiar with a CONTRIBUTING file and with using commit messages to exchange information about changes, but the fact remains that two people who may not be in the same room at the same time will have to communicate the presence of a new branch or tag. Otherwise the burden will be on the maintainer to frequently check the git log to see whether any new branches appear, and vice versa, the contributor will have to keep pulling tags and branches until they notice theirs has been merged or rejected. Git is not an effective communication tool, that's what the web interfaces are for.

Answer (score 0):

In short, GitHub and other services decorate around basic Git functionality to provide people with added statistics and buttons that fit most of the industry standardized workflows.

> how to review code before pushing it to (certain) branches

Even on GitHub, you have to *push* before the review is performed. So, push or put the code somewhere, appoint an integrator (in charge of integrating new changes and review them) and have that integrator review the code and maintain a stable versioning branch of the code in some repository.

If you have a colleague working on the same PC, you may achive the same in several ways. I list a few:

#### 1 working copy, branch out

Have a single working copy (`git init`), you both create branches so that you work on separate branches. Define an integration branch were you will merge content. Pro: no need to push/pull locally. Cons: each one of you **must** leave the workspace clean everytime they leave. Either commit or stash.

#### 2 working copies, one blessed

Have one of you in charge of the "blessed" one the working copy (`git init`) and clone it locally somewhere else. Pros: you may leave the workspace as dirty as you wish. Cons: one of you **must** be in charge of the blessed one and do the merges. The clone can be erased at any time, but the blessed must be preserved and kept nice and clean.

#### 1 bare, n working copies

Have a bare repository (`git init --bare`) as remote of your current best working copy. Push the latest stable code to it, to the integration branch. Design a workflow for integration. Clone it to create new working copies. Perform integration on the stable branch in onw of the working copies and push it to the bare. Pull from the bare the latest stable code. Pros: the cleanest solution. Cons: requires that one of you possess a good knowledge of versioning theory, and one of you *must* be the owner and responsible for the history of the code.

Comment: Beautiful explanation! Thank you very much!